# SQL- Combining multiple rows into 1 field without trailing zero for blank last field

Tags: sql

I have a table with a some data that I need to put into 1 field. The table looks like:

```
FacID |  RxBatch  |  RxNo  |  Split  |  AdminTimeNo  |  AdminTime
123      TEST        2222       1            1          07:00 AM
123      TEST        2222       1            2
123      TEST        2222       1            3
123      TEST        2222       1            4          08:00 PM
123      TEST        2222       1            5
```

There can be times between each of the 4 AdminTimeNo (so it maybe be 07:00 AM, 10:00 AM, 02:00 PM, 08:00 PM, etc. Completely variable). There is always an 'empty' AdminTime in the last row (regardless of what AdminTimeNo the last time is in. That 'empty' AdminTime is not a null field, just nothing). There are no null fields in the table.

I have tried using the following STUFF function to put the AdminTimes into a single field:

```
STUFF((
    Select ',' + RxAdminTimes.AdminTime
    FROM RxAdminTimes
    Where RxAdminTimes.RxNo = 2222
    AND RxAdminTimes.FacID = 123
    AND RxAdminTimes.RxBatch = 'TEST'
    AND RxAdminTimes.Split = '1'
    FOR XML Path (''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

But this leaves me with commas everywhere (07:00  AM,,,08:00 PM,)

I added a couple of REPLACE functions to the STUFF function above (to compensate for various places AdminTimes may be:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(STUFF((
                        Select ',' + RxAdminTimes.AdminTime
                        FROM FWDB.RX.RxAdminTimes
                        Where RxAdminTimes.RxNo = 731005
                        AND RxAdminTimes.FacID = 2657
                        AND RxAdminTimes.PatID = 10014695
                        AND RxAdminTimes.RxBatch = 'CF'
                        AND RxAdminTimes.Split = '1'
                        FOR XML Path (''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''),',,,',','),',,',',')
```

That yields better results (based on where AdminTime is in relation to AdminTimeNo), but I have a trailing ',' every time. (In this case, the above yields "07:00 AM,09:00 PM,"). Any more REPLACE functions to remove the single comma also remove the comma I do want. And I haven't figured out a way to grab the comma only with 'nothing' behind it.

How can I do this, without a trailing comma. I know the STUFF function removes the leading comma, but I have not had luck finding a solution to this with an empty field at the end. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filter out empty values in the subquery:

```
STUFF((
    Select ',' + RxAdminTimes.AdminTime
    FROM RxAdminTimes
    Where RxAdminTimes.RxNo = 2222
    AND RxAdminTimes.FacID = 123
    AND RxAdminTimes.RxBatch = 'TEST'
    AND RxAdminTimes.Split = '1'
    AND RxAdminTimes.AdminTime <> ''  --> remove empty values
    FOR XML Path (''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: of course! It would be something super simple and easy that I hadn't considered. This worked perfectly, thank you so much1